# MatStepper can't change page after using selectedIndex

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I need in some cases to go to a specific step and I'm changing it programmatically using `this.step` to change the value for`[selectedIndex]`.

I've done this on ngOnInit to have the value for step before the stepper will appear. The view looks ok, the user can do what he need to do in the wanted step, but after that the user need to continue to next steps.

Let's assume the value of `this.step` is 2. After the user finish to complete the data on this step he need to change the page to the next step. And I have a button for this but I don't know why the method from (click) directive it's executed but the step it's not changing. And what's intresting.. if I'm starting to use the stepper from the step 0..and go from 0 everythings works great. What can I do to solve this issue? Cause I need sometimes to start from another step and continue from this step.

````
<button (click)="doSomeStuff()" 
      matStepperNext > Next
</button>```


<mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper [linear]="true" [selectedIndex]="step">
    <mat-step [editable]="true">....</mat-step>
    <mat-step [editable]="false">....</mat-step>    
    <mat-step [editable]="false">....</mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
````

Comment: can you post the code for the doSomeStuff() method?

Comment: @samlu it's not that relevant.. are some iterations of the data and calls to save the data in database. If you remove the directive with the calling of the method...the issue will be there anyway.

Comment: You said you have a button to change to the next step. Are you not trying to assign the next value for `this.step` in that `doSomeStuff()` method?

Comment: no, the value for ```this.step``` I'm changing only if I need to go specific to the step ```2``` and I'm doing this on ngOnInit.

Comment: And when I'm at the step 2 after the step is completed when the user press next on the button I'm using ```matStepperNext``` but nothing happens. And I don't know why, because If I'm opening the stepper from the beginning and I'm going step by step..everything works

Comment: you want to navigate to specific mat step programetically?

Comment: @Chellappan basically yes and I've done that using  ```[selectedIndex]``` to go to step 2. But after that, I want to go using the buttons to the step 3, step 4.etc. But I can't

Comment: do you have button outside mat step component?

Comment: @Chellappan no, it's inside. And that's why it's frustrating..because if I'm using the stepper starting from step 0, evrything it's ok and works. But If I'm starting from step 2 and want to go to step 3..I can't

Comment: If it possible can you create stakcblitz?

Comment: Hey Guys, is this issue fixed because I face the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after some investigation I've discovered that if you set a step `[editable]="false"`, changing `stepper.selectedIndex`, the relative functions `stepper.forward()` and `stepper.next()` and the buttons `matStepperNext` and `matStepperPrevious` won't work.

If you need to use the attribute `[editable]="false"`, a workaround is to set it to true, change step and then set again the attribute to false.

```
  // actualIndex = 2
  const stepIndex = 1;
  this._stepper.steps.toArray()[stepIndex].editable = true;
  this._stepper.previous();
  this._stepper.steps.toArray()[stepIndex].editable = false;
```